# отфильтровать массив по месяцу

Tags: javascript

есть массив с данными

```
data =    [
                        {"title": "todo1", "date": "2020-01-01", "complete": true},
                        {"title": "todo2", "date": "2020-01-22", "complete": false},
                        {"title": "todo3", "date": "2020-02-04", "complete": false},
                        {"title": "todo4", "date": "2020-02-12", "complete": true},
                        {"title": "todo5", "date": "2020-02-21", "complete": false},
                        {"title": "todo6", "date": "2020-03-04", "complete": true},
                        {"title": "todo7", "date": "2020-04-02", "complete": false},
                        {"title": "todo8", "date": "2020-05-07", "complete": true}
                                ]
```

мне нужно отфильтровать его по date. по второму месяцу, т е должно быть
"date": "2020-02-04"
"date": "2020-02-12"
"date": "2020-02-21"

data.filter((elem) => elem.date == и тут я не понимаю как правильно написать);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```js
data = [
  {"title": "todo1", "date": "2020-01-01", "complete": true},
  {"title": "todo2", "date": "2020-01-22", "complete": false},
  {"title": "todo3", "date": "2020-02-04", "complete": false},
  {"title": "todo4", "date": "2020-02-12", "complete": true},
  {"title": "todo5", "date": "2020-02-21", "complete": false},
  {"title": "todo6", "date": "2020-03-04", "complete": true},
  {"title": "todo7", "date": "2020-04-02", "complete": false},
  {"title": "todo8", "date": "2020-05-07", "complete": true}
];

console.log(data.filter((elem) => elem.date.split('-')[1] === '02'));
```